# Changing iFrame size with Javascript blinks in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage, iframe-resizer

I'm changing the iframe size dynamically using the native libs `ResizeObserver` and `PostMessage` but each time the iframe changes size (`width`and `height`) in both **Chrome** and **Edge** it blinks.
It's really strange behaviour since in **Firefox** and **Safari** it works as expected.

Here is my code

```
// Child window
const resize = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  window.parent.postMessage({ updateIframeSize: { width, height } }, *);
});

resize.observe(document.body);

// Main window
window.addEventListener('message', function (message) {
  const iframeSizeEvt = message.data.updateIframeSize;
    
  if (iframeSizeEvt) {
    const iframeTag = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    
    iframeTag.style.width = `${iframeSizeEvt.width}px`;
    iframeTag.style.height = `${iframeSizeEvt.height}px`;
  }
});

// Iframe
<iframe id="myIframe" src="MY_IFRAME_URL" style="position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100px; max-width: 100%; height: 100px; max-height: 100%; border: 0; background-color: transparent; opacity: 1; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1000000; box-sizing: border-box;"></iframe>
```

I also tested adding `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` on the iframe but didn't work out.
Does somebody knows how to fix this strange blink behaviour?

Comment: It makes sense that it blinks because it is repainting the iframe. There are a few things I would try to mitigate the blink. 1: I would try and debounce the function you are passing to resize observer (although resizeobserver might already mitigate when it fires). Check out this link: https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf. 2: I would hide the resizing of the iframe behind a loader icon of some sort, so it looks nicer. 3. Instead of changing the size of the iframe element, change the size of the parent, give iframe percentage size

Comment: Thanks for your answer James!
Unfortunately both solutions (1 and 3) didn't work. About the "loader icon" it could be a good solution but for my project that can not be used since is a ChatBot and i have requirements for implementation.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. There is one more thing I can think of to try. Make your iframe responsive like in this w3 tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_iframes.asp. However, instead of giving it an aspect ratio, calculate how much downward padding you need based on the height of the iframe. So the downward padding of the container could equal the height of the frame divided by the width of the container, multiplied by 100 to get a percentage.

Comment: Thanks but, no success, damm im really lost. I've made a video to share my problem https://youtu.be/Aof52jagVKk. The div element is the wrapper of my iframe and the iframe just contains a simple div blue box. Each time the div wrapper change is size the blue box blinks.

Comment: After huge investigation and reported to Chromium, this blink is due "site-isolation" setting. If disabled it will fix the blink issue.
See more: http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation

Comment: The best solution is to define a fixed size for the iframe and add a wrapper with overflow hidden. The wrapper will be the element with dynamic size.